# How to implement split_part () in Azure Data Factory Expression

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I'm trying to implement a join task in the pipeline of Azure, the join condition needs to come with split_part() which I think it's from the feature of Snowflake or other DBMS.

I can see there are 2 build-in functions inside the Azure datafactory, split() and regexSplit().
However, both cannot return the assigned value after split.

Ex my join condition value should be **split_part(Stack_Overflow, '_', 2)**
and it will return flow as the join value.
Does anyone know what I can use to implement it with Azure built in function??
Thanks
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Code should be
**split('Stack_Overflow', '_')[2]**

Note the index of Azure array starts with 1 not 0.

Reference
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/concepts-data-flow-expression-builder